# Mongo how to search for a field of element of array?

Tags: mongodb

I try to explain

I have a lot of 'companies' in a collection.

each company has a field like this

```
"carriers" : [
    {
        "priority" : NumberInt(1), 
        "carrier_id" : "a77c9d80-0683-11ec-bec1-074eeabae60b"
    }, 
    {
        "priority" : NumberInt(2), 
        "carrier_id" : "a77d8720-0683-11ec-b6d4-6765509a5216"
    }
]
```

Having a `carrier_id`, how can I search every company where `carrier_id` is equal to searched one?

Comment: if you want to filter main documents then use dot notation in query `"carriers.carrier_id": "a77d8720-0683-11ec-b6d4-6765509a5216"`, for more details you can refer the detailed documentation [Query on Embedded/Nested Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#specify-equality-match-on-a-nested-field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dot notation works transparently over array elements. You can do:

```
{'carriers.carrier_id' => 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

as I know you want to search all docs that have specific  `carrier_id` for example `"a77c9d80-0683-11ec-bec1-074eeabae60b"`.
so when carrier_id is in array we should use `$elemMatch` to find value in array.
in this query we said mongo find all docs that array of `carriers` have a `carrier_id` of "a77c9d80-0683-11ec-bec1-074eeabae60b" and at the end of code I add `toArray()` to get docs as array

```
db.collection.find({carriers:{$elemMatch:{carrier_id:"a77c9d80-0683-11ec-bec1-074eeabae60b"}}}).toArray()
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly you can use `$filter` in a `$project` stage:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "carriers": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$carriers",
          "as": "c",
          "cond": {
            "$eq": [
              "$$c.carrier_id",
              "a77c9d80-0683-11ec-bec1-074eeabae60b"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/x0wxvc6OuBm)